# Select data from 2 tables and match on 2 fields (oracle sql developer)

Tags: oracle, join

I have two tables

```
TABLE1
-DATADATE
-ISIN
-INDEXNAME

TABLE2
-AS_OF_DATE
-ISSUER_ISIN
-GPSCORE
-SPSCORE
```

I would like to merge the two tables by matching on:

```
AS_OF_DATE = DATADATE
and 
ISIN = ISSUER_ISIN
```

Comment: Please read 'stackexchange homework' & [mcve] & show what you tried & explain how you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 tb1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 tb2 
ON tb1.DATADATE = tb2.AS_OF_DATE 
AND tb1.ISIN = tb2.ISSUER_ISIN
```

Comment: How would I match on mm/yyyy for both dates?  I just realised that one date is the end of the month, and the other is the first of the month.